# TS6137: Cannot import type declaration files when importing from @types

Tags: typescript

I am working on lets say **package A** that is intended to be used in another **package B** (sort of as a plugin) but my **package A** depends on the types defined in **package B**. I am using Typescript 4.3.4

My initial thought was to import just the types from **package B** into **package A** but that presented me with the following problem:

1. I installed types to `node_modules/@types/packageA` inside **packageB** and when I tried to import with `import { someType } from '@types/packageA'` and build I got the following error: `TS6137: Cannot import type declaration files`.
2. Now if I instead installed types to `node_modules/packageA-types` inside **packageB** and import with `import { someType } from 'packageA-types'` it works and I do not get the error when I build.

**Why does the first method fail and why does the second method work?**

I read a few other stackoverflow posts that talked about normal/local vs global/ambient Typescript modules but I didn't quite understand how that played into this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the compiler resolves to importing from @types/package if you import directly from the package.